LVGL Fonts <unnamed enum>
I'm struggling with using any fonts in LVGL 8.
No matter what I do, I the error below...
error: cannot convert 'unnamed enum' to 'const lv_font_t' {aka 'const _lv_font_t'}**
It's probably really obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out and there aren't any full worked examples.
I've got the following code...
static lv_style_t style;
lv_style_init(&style);
lv_style_set_text_font(&style, LV_STATE_DEFAULT, &lv_font_unscii_16);

and I've ensured that in my lv_conf.h file I've got the following...
#define LV_FONT_UNSCII_16 1

...but when I try to assign the font to the style in the code above, I get an <> error. I've also tried with a few other built-in fonts that are enabled, such as lv_font_montserrat_16.
I've tried declaring it as an extern using LV_FONT_DECLARE(lv_font_unscii_16), as an extern with extern const lv_font_t lv_font_unscii_16; and a few similar techniques, but none of them have worked so far.
And given the 10 minute compile time, I'm really starting to lose patience with what //should// be a very simple thing.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This was an issue with so much older documentation/examples out there on the internet.
The simple answer is that they had changed the syntax of the function. The second parameter has been removed, so the correct syntax is simply...
lv_style_set_text_font(&style, &lv_font_unscii_16);

